# jQuery modifying CSS - when does browser render?

Tags: jquery, css

My jQuery code adds and removes multiple style classes. Does the browser re-render with every line of javascript code?  For example:

```
$(this).addClass('text1-hidden');
$(this).removeClass('text-2-hidden');
$(this).addClass('text3-shown');
$(this).removeClass('text-4-shown');
```

When does the browser re-draw things?

Comment: The changes are made right away, unless it's an animation, in which case the animation is started right away. Have you tried it and experienced anything different?

Comment: I have much text that I restyle, so I need this re-styling to be very efficient. This re-styling is a little slow on mobile devices.

Comment: That's probably because JavaScript is slow on your mobile devices, or because your mobile browser is running out of memory. Try reducing the footprint of the mobile page first -- images, unnecessary DOM elements, etc.  Voting to close since your real problem is unsolvable based on the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

All DOM-Based changes (Classname changes e. g.) are made immediately on the fly without a human measureable delay.

The Stylechanges affected by assigning/removing new classes to an element will also take into affect immediatley.

Answer (score 0):

The browser, generally speaking, renders changes as it reads them. Obviously if your code is contained within a function that requires a specific event or callback in order to be triggered then it will do nothing until that event/callback occurs.

Answer (score 0):

1. The JS engine **WILL** execute procedurally, line-by-line
2. Upon execution, the browser will act procedurally as well

The code will **not** be clustered to do some garbage like this:

```
// this is perfectly valid code *** IF *** this is what you wish for the code to do
$(this).addClass('text1-hidden text3-shown');
$(this).removeClass('text-2-hidden text-4-shown');
```

If the lines above were to magically happen then that would be a design decision by the jQuery team.

If the jQuery team actually implemented something like this without forcing it to be an opt-in option then I would stop using jQuery.

Write code that does what you need it to do. The beauty of programming is that it does not "guess", it just does things in the order which you programmed it unless of course you get into `REGEX hell` then I bid you the best of luck.